# Solr query using results of subquery

Tags: solr, lucene

I wonder is there a way to perform in Solr something similar to:
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field1 IN (SELECT f1 FROM table2)`
I read about nested query here - https://lucidworks.com/2009/03/31/nested-queries-in-solr/ - but still don't understand if I could do so and if it's possible then how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do so, using Solr's `join` statement.
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join